# Anylogic .mdl load fail

Tags: anylogic

Anylogic is failing to load a .mdl file, here is the error and link to the file.

Error:

```
com.anylogic.ui.gch: Encountered " "," "," " at line157, column 70
Was expecting
   "-" ...
```

https://import.cdn.thinkific.com/453531/courses/1323397/DiabetesStockandFlowcore-210614-091435.mdl

Comment: .mdl files are made by Simulink. AnyLogic only works with .alp files.

Comment: Menu Open, the file dialog three open choices; .alp, Vensim Models (.mdl), then all files. The error looks like it coming from a parser.

Comment: Did you try menu->open or menu->import? i.e. did you follow [this](https://anylogic.help/anylogic/system-dynamics/vensim-import.html). And are you sure it is Vensim and not matlab simulink? they're both .mdl files.

Comment: Yes, now.  same error.
Looked at file, text with system dynamics stuff. and download stated vensim.

Comment: yeah, ok i am able to replicate the problem. this looks like it is deep inside the parser code. unfortunately it seems that only someone from AnyLogic would be able to help.

Answer (score 0):

anyLogic doesn't support the last version of vensim (or vice-versa) so you won't be able to import vensim models anymore...